# Convert special characters like ë,à,é,ä all to e,a,e,a? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sdk, character

Is there a simple way in objective c to convert all special characters like ë,à,é,ä to the normal characters like e en a?

Comment: How about char lol = 'é'; and then just - some value to make it an e?

Comment: I know but doing this for every characters will make my codes messy I think....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep, and it's pretty simple:

```
NSString *src = @"Convert special characters like ë,à,é,ä all to e,a,e,a? Objective C";
NSData *temp = [src dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *dst = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"converted: %@", dst);
```

Running that on my machine produces:

```
EmptyFoundation[69299:a0f] converted: Convert special characters like e,a,e,a all to e,a,e,a? Objective C
```

Basically, we're asking the string to transform itself it an `NSData` (ie, a byte array) that represents the characters in the string in the ASCII character set.  Since not all of the characters in the original string are in ASCII, [we tell the string that it's OK to do a "lossy" conversion](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-dataUsingEncoding_allowLossyConversion_).  In other words, it's OK to turn "é" into "e", and so on.

Once we've got our byte array, we simply turn it back into a string, and we're done! :)

Answer (score 2):

### CFStringTransform

CFStringTransform is the solution when you are dealing with a specific language. It transliterates strings in ways that simplify normalization, indexing, and searching. For example, it can remove accent marks using the option `kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks`:

```
CFMutableStringRef string = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, CFSTR("Schläger"));
   CFStringTransform(string, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks,
     false);
... => string is now “Schlager” CFRelease(string);
```

`CFStringTransform` is even more powerful when you are dealing with non-Latin writing systems such as **Arabic** or **Chinese**. It can convert many writing systems to **Latin** script, making normalization much simpler.

For example, you can convert **Chinese** script to **Latin** script like this:

```
CFMutableStringRef string = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, CFSTR("你好"));
CFStringTransform(string, NULL, kCFStringTransformToLatin, false);
... => string is now “nˇı hˇao”
CFStringTransform(string, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks,
false);
... => string is now “ni hao” CFRelease(string);
```

Notice that the option is simply `kCFStringTransformToLatin`.

> The source language is not required. You can hand almost any string to
> this transform without having to know first what language it is in.
> CFStringTransform can also transliterate from Latin script to other
> writing systems such as Arabic, Hangul, Hebrew, and Thai.

References: [iOS 7 Programming: Pushing to the limits](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118818342.html)